# Grep searching for files which are not existing

Tags: grep

I wanted to search for the text " Starting kernel" in a directory, so I did this:

```
 [root@xilinx petalinux-v2013.10-final]# grep -r "Starting kernel"  
grep: warning: tools/packagemanager/lib/i686: recursive directory loop

grep: Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/rootfs/targetroot/etc/init.d/functions: No such file or directory
grep: Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/rootfs/targetroot/etc/rcS.d/S10flashdev: No such file or directory
grep: Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/rootfs/targetroot/mnt/net: No such file or directory
grep: Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/rootfs/targetroot/mnt/cf: No such file or directory
Binary file Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/pre-built/linux/images/u-boot.elf matches
Binary file Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/pre-built/linux/images/BOOT.BIN matches
Binary file Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/pre-built/linux/images/output.bin matches
```

Why is it searching in files that don't exist? Why am I getting these "No such file or directory" messages?

Also, why is it searching binary files when I gave it ASCII characters? Can a binary file contain a string like mine?

Answer (score 6):

That is most likely because those are links that point to no existing files.

You should look at one of the files e.g.:

```
ls -l Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/rootfs/targetroot/etc/init.d/functions
```

and then again do `ls` on where it points to.

You can also do:

```
ls -L Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/rootfs/targetroot/etc/init.d/functions
```

which will probably get you `cannot access: ....` as well.

Answer (score 6):

`grep`, by default, doesn't ignore non-existent or unreadable files.  You need to supply the `-s` or `--no-messages` option in order to make `grep` ignore those.  Quoting from `man grep`:

> ```
>    -s, --no-messages
>           Suppress  error  messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
>           Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not
>           conform to POSIX, because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved
>           like GNU grep's -q option.  USG-style grep also  lacked  -q  but
>           its  -s  option  behaved  like GNU grep.  Portable shell scripts
>           should avoid both -q and -s and  should  redirect  standard  and
>           error output to /dev/null instead.  (-s is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Because you use `-r` option, so `grep` will search recursively, include symlinks.

```
-R, -r, --recursive
              Read all files under each directory, recursively;
              this is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
```

Like @Anthon's answer, maybe some symlinks under parent directory is not existed or broken.

By default, `grep` also search string in binary file:

```
--binary-files=TYPE
              If the first few bytes of a file indicate that the file
              contains binary data, assume that  the  file  is  of  type  TYPE. 
              By default, TYPE is binary, and grep normally outputs either a 
              one-line message saying that a binary file matches, or no message 
              if there is no match. If TYPE is without-match, grep assumes that a 
              binary file does not match; this is equivalent to the -I option. 
              If TYPE is text, grep processes a binary file as if it were text;
              this is equivalent to the -a option. Warning: grep --binary-files=text
              might output binary garbage, which can have nasty side effects 
              if the output is  a  terminal  and  if  the terminal driver
              interprets some of it as commands.
```

A binary file can also contain some strings. You can do a simple check by using `strings` command on a binary file:

```
strings /usr/bin/basename
```

Answer (score 0):

`man grep`  contains :

```
-I     Process a binary file as if it did not  contain  matching  data;
       this is equivalent to the --binary-files=without-match option.
```

Comment: This partially answers half of the question; you really need to explain things when you post answers.